# Context hierarchy in Spring Boot based tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

My Spring Boot application is started like this:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder()
  .sources(ParentCtxConfig.class)
  .child(ChildFirstCtxConfig.class)
  .sibling(ChildSecondCtxConfig.class)
  .run(args);
```

Config classes are annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. As a result, I have one root context and two child web contexts.

I want to write integration test and I would like to have same context hierarchy there. I want at least to test first child context (configured with `ChildFirstCtxConfig.class`) with his parent context (`ParentCtxConfig.class`).  How can I achieve that?

Currently I autowired `ApplicationContext` in my test so I can inspect it. I have this class annotation in the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ParentCtxConfig.class, ChildFirstCtxConfig.class }, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

but that will produce single context and I want parent-child hierarchy.
I assume that I should annotate my test with `@ContextHierarchy` annotation.

Changing my test annotation to this seems to work exactly the same like previous example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ParentCtxConfig.class, ChildFirstCtxConfig.class })
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

But if I want to introduce `@ContextHierarchy` and have something like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy({
        @ContextConfiguration(name = "root", classes = ParentCtxConfig.class),
        @ContextConfiguration(name = "child", classes = ChildFirstCtxConfig.class)
})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

context is not started because of bean defined in parent context can't be found/autowired in child context. Setting `loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class` doesn't help.

Sample code: [GitHub](https://github.com/stojsavljevic/multi-ctx/tree/master/multi-ctx-app-builder)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** [This issue was fixed in Spring Boot 1.5.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8000) as mentioned by Peter Davis.

This is a limitation of `@SpringBootTest`. Move accurately, it's a limitation of `SpringBootContextLoader`. You could work around it by using a custom context loader that configures the parent context or with a `ContextCustomizer` the factory for which would need to be listed in `spring.factories`. Here's a rough example of the latter:

#### src/test/resources/META-INF/spring.factories:

```
org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizerFactory=\
com.alex.demo.ctx.HierarchyContextCustomizerFactory
```

#### src/test/java/com/alex/demo/ctx/HierarchyContextCustomizerFactory.java:

```
package com.alex.demo.ctx;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfigurationAttributes;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizer;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizerFactory;
import org.springframework.test.context.MergedContextConfiguration;

public class HierarchyContextCustomizerFactory implements ContextCustomizerFactory {

    @Override
    public ContextCustomizer createContextCustomizer(Class<?> testClass,
            List<ContextConfigurationAttributes> configAttributes) {
        return new ContextCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customizeContext(ConfigurableApplicationContext context,
                    MergedContextConfiguration mergedConfig) {
                if (mergedConfig.getParentApplicationContext() != null) {
                    context.setParent(mergedConfig.getParentApplicationContext());
                }

            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy. I hope that support for `@ContextHierarchy` will be added soon in Spring Boot. Here is the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8000) for anyone who needs it.

Comment: it should be under `src/test/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson I got an error: IllegalStateException: Already associated with parent BeanFactory

Comment: @idmitriev Thanks, I’ve corrected the file paths. The error sounds like you may be using Boot 1.5 or later where described workaround is no longer necessary

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 1.4.2